# How do I write up my models' code to fetch according to my database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, getter-setter

[FirebaseDatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su9On.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su9On.png)
[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjYZg.png)[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu5w7.png)[Ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbVwn.png)[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpZUL.png)

Comment: You should need to add more description about your problem and what issue you're facing.

Comment: I cant load the images to the layout when the activity launches,

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: You've also included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to change:
val model = snapshot.getValue(BestDealModel::class.java)
tempList.add(model!!)
to
val model = itemSnapshot.getValue(BestDealModel::class.java)
tempList.add(model!!)